# Is there a c like 'Exp1 ? Exp2 : Exp3' in Python?

Tags: python, refactoring

i would like to know if there is an adequate python alternative for my beloved C Makro `'Exp1 ? Exp2 : Exp3'.`

I already tried to google but can't seem to find anything.

Example:

```
x = 0.5
(x > 0) ? 1 : 0



if(type == "release"):
        release = True
else:
        release = False
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) may help

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this in your case

```
1 if x > 0 else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Python 3.x**:

[Ternary Operators](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html):

```
trueExp if expr. else falseExp
```

**i.e**:

```
x = 0.5
print(1 if x > 0 else 0)   # 1
```

For **Python 2.5** and older versions:

[Is there an equivalent of C’s ”?:” ternary operator?](https://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator):

`[expr.] and [trueExp] or [falseExp ]`

**i.e**:

```
x = 0.5
print((x > 0) and 1 or 0)   # 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a [*ternary operator*](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html).

There are multiple ways to achieve this in Python, but you will most often find this construct:

```py
x = 0.5
print(1 if x > 0 else 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python does not have *exactly* something like `Exp1 ? Exp2 : Exp3`.

However, you can  condense if-else statements into a single line. Something like

`Exp2 if Exp1 else Exp3` would be somewhat Python equivalent of what you are looking for.

(I have followed the order in which you have written the C code)

More precisely, it is something like:

`TrueVal if Expression else FalseVal`.

Comment: Can you elaborate as in what exactly is general @lukas